# On Equivalence of Algebraic Expressions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, reference-request, definition

We all know what does it mean when two algebraic expressions are equivalent, however, I'd like to know if you know a book of formal mathematics that define such thing (preferably on college level).

Most of the books I've been looking do not define the equivalence of algebraic expressions, and take such notion for granted. I'd love some literature about it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Based on many of the questions that I see here, I’d question your opening claim.